# Dynamically create/destroy custom widgets in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm just starting with Qt. I would like to make a GUI with custom widgets that can be used to display/edit my custom datatypes . I would also like to be able to dynamically create/destroy these widgets (without destroying the underlying data).

I've tried to accomplish this by storing a list of my data items (`dataContainer`) in the main Window class, and passing a pointer to a `dataContainer` to the constructor of my widget (`customWidget`), which stores this pointer. Then `customWidget` can alter the underlying data via this pointer.

The code below allows the user to repeatedly add `dataContainer` instances to the list and edit each of their "names". When I run this, everything works fine as long I don't actually edit the name, but if I do edit the name and then click the "Add" button, I get a segfault. This segfault occurs during the destructor of `customWidget` during `delete myWidget;` in `Window::add()`.

Two questions:

1. Why does this code crash? Am I not allowed to dynamically create/destroy widgets like this?
2. Is there a more appropriate way to accomplish this?

I apologize if there's something basic I'm missing here, but I've been up-and-down lots of forums and tutorials, and not found anything helpful.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include "window.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Window mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**window.h**

```cpp
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "customwidget.h"

class Window : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Window();

  public slots:    
    void add();    

private:

  // the main data structure
  QList<dataContainer> dataList;

  // the widget that displays the custom data
  customWidget *myWidget;     

  QVBoxLayout *mainLayout;
  QPushButton *addButton;

};

#endif
```

**window.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QtGui>
#include "window.h"

Window::Window(){

  // start with a single piece of data in the list
  dataContainer newData;
  dataList.append(newData);

  // create layout container
  mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
  mainLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);

  // make the Add button, and connect its clicked() SIGNAL
  // to our add() SLOT
  addButton=new QPushButton(tr("Add"),this);
  connect(addButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(add()));
  mainLayout->addWidget(addButton);  

  // create a custom widget to display our data and
  // give it a pointer to the data it will display/modify
  myWidget = new customWidget(this,&(dataList.last()) );
  mainLayout->addWidget(myWidget);

  setLayout(mainLayout);   

}

void Window::add(){

  // create a new piece of data, and add to the list
  dataContainer newData;
  dataList.append(newData);

  // debug: show the current list
  qDebug() << "Data List(" << dataList.size() << ")";
  for (int i=0;i<dataList.size();i++){
    qDebug() << dataList[i].getName().c_str();
  }

  // delete the old widget
  delete myWidget;

  // and make a new widget with the new data
  myWidget = new customWidget(this,&(dataList.last()) );
  mainLayout->addWidget(myWidget);   

}
#include "window.moc"
```

**customwidget.h**

```cpp
#ifndef CUSTOMWIDGET_H
#define CUSTOMWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include <string>

class dataContainer {
  private:

    std::string name;

  public:
    dataContainer(){name="oooh";};
    std::string getName()const{return name;};
    std::string setName(const std::string& n){name=n;};

};

class customWidget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT

  private:
    dataContainer *data;

  public slots:
    void nameChangedSlot(const QString&);

  public:
    customWidget(QWidget *parent,  dataContainer *d);

};
#endif
```

**customwidget.cpp**

```cpp
#include "customwidget.h"

customWidget::customWidget(QWidget *parent,  dataContainer *d) : QWidget(parent) {

  // store a pointer to the data that we want to alter
  data = d;

  // create an edit box and initialize it with the data name
  QVBoxLayout *mainLayout=new QVBoxLayout(this);
  QLineEdit *edit=new QLineEdit(QString::fromStdString(data->getName()),this);
  mainLayout->addWidget(edit);

  connect(edit,SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)),this,SLOT(nameChangedSlot(const QString&)));

}

void customWidget::nameChangedSlot(const QString& name){

  // alter the contents of our data based on the changed string
  data->setName(name.toStdString());

}

#include "customwidget.moc"
```

Comment: You add your widget to the `mainLayout` with this code `mainLayout->addWidget(myWidget);` but when you delete the widget you need first remove the widget from the mainLayout widget collection.

Comment: That doesn't fix it. I put `mainLayout->removeWidget(myWidget);` before `delete myWidget;`. I've also tried using `disconnect` and `myWidget->deleteLater()`. It also wouldn't explain why it _only_ segfaults if the text has been edited.

Comment: why don't you reuse widget? multiple creation and deletion may cause memory leak.

Comment: I don't want to reuse the widget because I'd like to use the same graphical space to display different widgets for different data types (i.e. polymorphism). This is a simplified example, but in the real thing, the custom widget would contain several basic widgets. Why should multiple creation/deletion create a memory leak?

Comment: Deleting a widget from a layout it safe, without removing it explicitly before.

Answer (score 4):

A widget that is added to a layout can not be deleted directly. Instead, you can try below code which deletes a specific widget and corresponding layout item from layout:

```
QLayoutItem* item;
while ( ( item = mainLayout->takeAt( 0 ) ) != NULL )
{
    if(item->widget() == myWidget){
        delete item->widget();
        delete item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, although now I can't seem to get it to iterate through the list. Something happens and my list.count() returns -someLargeNum ?, but at any rate I believe this is a new issue.