# QT Quick how to have different tabs depending on the item type

Tags: c++, qt, settings

Sorry for my QT language. QT is new to me, and i don't no the exact words in the QT language.

My goal is to have an editor for an item list. All items are with their names on the left side. On the right side i want to have an editor with sliders, switches, etc for this item . But this view depends on the type of the item.

In my case i need a idea how to

update a right view with object data and laoding a qml depending of the type with the different settings.

I appreciate any hints.

best regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227155/dynamically-create-destroy-custom-widgets-in-qt

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#currentItemChanged

Comment: tebbed `QDockwidget` with widget itself as right area and widget title as left side?

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do for this is actually have several different trees of widgets. For itemA, show widgetA (with his children) and hide the others. For itemB, show widgetB (with his children), et cetera.

It takes a little setting up, but it's fast and not hard to code. In effect, it becomes very similar to a tabbed view.

You can use widgetA->hide() and widgetB->show().